# Detect Graphical Login In Bash

Tags: linux, gnome, bash

I am managing computers and accounts in my classroom, which is a CentOS 5.5 environment.  I am trying to figure out how to use the .bashrc file (or similar) to ensure that a task runs when a user logs in via Gnome/GDM, that is, logs into a GUI session, but that that task does not run when a user logs in via SSH or other terminal logins.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably take a look at the [XDG autostart specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html), which allows you to have applications start upon desktop login.  Since bash and other shells do not follow the XDG specs (obviously, they are UNIX shells, not DEs), you essentially achieve what you're looking for, but without worrying about shells at all.

Comment: That sounds like the best solution for the general case - but in this specific case, investigating the value of $DISPLAY is probably good enough, and more parsimonious of my time.

Comment: If you already have .desktop files for your application, it is pretty simple; just drop one in the appropriate directory.  I'm not sure where in the (GUI) login process a shell is spawned.  It's also pretty easy to do strange things if you use a shell's init files if the user does not use that shell, or if they start multiple shells.  I mentioned the autostart spec because that provides a deterministic method: someone already invented those wheels.  :-)

Comment: Oh yeah, those wheels are interesting and useful.  But I can get away with the quick-and-dirty version because my use case involves users who would probably be lucky to distinguish the bash shell from a conch shell.

Answer (score 2):

Look for the presence of the DISPLAY environment variable

```
if [ x$DISPLAY != x ] ; then
  #graphical
fi
```

Comment: And if someone uses `ssh -X`?

Comment: Then they have a graphic session.

Answer (score 0):

check the value of $DISPLAY